# Angular 2 multiple components

Tags: angular

It seemed like I completely confused with Angular 2 concept. I'd like to have three components on the page that defined this way in app.component.html (this is should be the entry point):

```
<bp-header></bp-header>
<bp-home></bp-home>
<bp-footer></bp-footer>
```

And this is main component (app.component.ts):

```
import { Component }          from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES }  from '@angular/router';
import {HeaderComponent} from "./header.component"
import {FooterComponent} from "./footer.component"
import {HomeComponent} from "./home.component"
@Component({
  selector: 'bp-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app/app.component.css'],
  directives: [HeaderComponent, FooterComponent, HomeComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

Bu there is nothing when I open home page as well as no errors in console.

Comment: are the selector attributes of HeaderComponent, FooterComponent, HomeComponent bp-header, bp-home and bp-footer?

Comment: @eltonkamami, yes, that's right.

Comment: is there a `<bp-app></bp-app>` tag in the document?

Comment: @eltonkamami, this tag defined in index.html

Comment: can you update your question with more codes, please ? :) 
It will be best if `index.html` and main.ts is there ? You should use `Angular-cli` for your projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, final solution is to put header and footer directives inside template this way that bp-header and bp-footer are separate components.

```
import { Component }          from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES }  from '@angular/router';
import {HeaderComponent} from "./header.component"
import {FooterComponent} from "./footer.component"
import {HomeComponent} from "./home.component"
@Component({
  selector: 'bp-app',
  templat: '<bp-header></bp-header><bp-footer></bp-footer>',
  styleUrls: ['app/app.component.css'],
  directives: [HeaderComponent, FooterComponent, HomeComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {}
```